# Angular Universal/SSR --> ERROR TypeError: ActionCable.WebSocket is not a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, actioncable

Using Actioncable js for front end as web sockets with rails on the server side, everything else works fine, while doing Angular SSR, it builds perfectly.
But when I hit a url it says

```
ERROR TypeError: ActionCable.WebSocket is not a constructor
```

I've already done: (global as any).WebSocket = require('ws'); and installed ws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
While doing Server Side Rendering, I was connecting to the websockets before the page was reaching the browser, hence it couldn't make the connection.

Angular has a way of detecting platform browser https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser

Just used it to detect if the code is in the browser and then make the socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

The back-end should be configured with:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/api/events").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```